# How can I use the data from a HashMap inside a method in another method?

Tags: java, scope

So i want to use the data that's being added to the HashMap in the clickRegister method in the Clicked method. But as far as i can see, the data is not saved outside the method. I'm assuming that's because it's outside of the scope? (I'm new to programming, so please correct me if i'm wrong). How can i accomplish this? And is it even possible?

```
public class Controller {
    private HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void Clicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        String cpr = cprField.getText();
        String password = passwordField.getText();

        if (userList.containsKey(cpr) && userList.containsValue(password)){
            Stage stage1;
            Parent root1;
            stage1 = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
            root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root1);
            stage1.setScene(scene);
            stage1.show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong credentials");
        }
    }

    public void clickRegister(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        if (cprFieldReg.getText().equals("") && passwordFieldReg.getText().equals("")){
            System.out.println("Fill in blank fields");
        } else {
            String username = cprFieldReg.getText();
            String password = passwordFieldReg.getText();

            userList.put(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The HashMap is defined as a global variable, so you can use it in the entire *instance*.  Ensure either with the debugger or console prints that the map is actually updated.  If so, ensure that you are not calling `clickRegister()` from controller object A and `Clicked()` from another controller object B.

Comment: @Babyburger What do you mean by using it as an entire instance? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to learn about how variable scopes work for variable declarations. It is pretty much the same in all languages. Declarations include method and constructor parameter declarations and variable declarations.

Possible scopes include:

- Global scope (a declaration is accessible from every part of a program)
- Class scope (a declaration is accessible from every part of a class)
- Instance scope (a declaration is accessible from instance methods)
- Method scope (a declaration is accessible from everywhere within a method)
- Local scope (a declaration is accessible from within curly braces)

You `cpr` variable is declared within a method, so its scope is restricted to that method. If you move the declaration out of the `Click` method, to just under the `HashMap` declaration, the variable will be accessible from the entire class. I think that is probably what you need for this situation.

Here is more information: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Scope

Comment: That didn't work:/ It just gives me this error: ```Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextField.getText()" because "this.cprField" is null"```

Comment: Congratulations, you fixed one problem, only to find it reveals the next problem. Debugging works like that. You will need to initialize `cprField` before its value is referenced.